Problem when trying to add primefaces to an existing jsf application in netbeans when trying to deploy on glassfish
here is my pom xml

here is my web xml

Here is the error and getting from Glass Fish logs

What i have tried
I tried to remove the prime faces dependency and redeploy the application and it did deploy successfully, tracing the problem to to be with the dependency. i am using Glass Fish version 6.1.2.
I checked on the version of java for both application and Glass Fish and there are both on version o 11.
